# Why todos.map is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a todo app with react. I cannot figure out why it is showing a

> typeerror:todos.map is not a function

I have checked if it is a problem related to array but I can't figure it out.

Below is my App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Form from "./component/form";
import TodoList from "./component/TodoList";
function App() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState(" ");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(" ");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>Todo</h1>
      </header>
      <Form
        todos={todos}
        inputText={inputText}
        setTodos={setTodos}
        setInputText={setInputText}
      />
      <TodoList todos={todos} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Below is the code in which todos is defined:

```
import React from "react";

const Form = ({ setInputText, todos, setTodos, inputText }) => {
  const inputTextMethod = (e) => {
    
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setInputText(e.target.value);
  };
  const submitTodoMethod = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([
      ...todos,
      {
        text: inputText,
        completed: false,
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
      },
    ]);
    setInputText(" ");
  };
```

And here I am trying to use map function:

```
import React from "react";
import Todo from "./todo";
const TodoList = ({ todos }) => {
  return (
    <div className="todo-container">
      <ul className="todo-list">
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <Todo text={todo.text} key={todo.id} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: `todos` is initially an empty string, which is why you get that error. Set the initial state to be an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you've initialized `todos` as a `String` in your `App.js`. So initially it's considering `todos` as a `String`, then you're setting `todos` as `Array` And you can't use `map` on the `String`. So re-write your `App.js` like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Form from "./component/form";
import TodoList from "./component/TodoList";
function App() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState(" ");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]); // change this
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>Todo</h1>
      </header>
      <Form
        todos={todos}
        inputText={inputText}
        setTodos={setTodos}
        setInputText={setInputText}
      />
      <TodoList todos={todos} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

All of the code expects `todos` to be an array.  But its initial state isn't an array, it's a string:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState(" ");
```

Initialize it to an empty array instead:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
```